# UpdateOne is not working with array of objects in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I try to update an object of an array in mongoDB. When the variable listID is not defined, it'll just update the first object of the array (but that's not what I want).

My goal is to add the word IDs, update the last_practiced field and increment the number of the word count field by the number of wordIDs.

I tried it with aggregation as well, but I couldn't get it to work.

**My current query**

```
Words.prototype.updatePersonalWordLists = async function(userID, listData) {

    const listID = listData.list_id
    const wordIDs = listData.word_ids
    const last_practiced = listData.last_practiced
    const numberOfNewWords = listData.word_ids.length
    
    const lists = await personalWordLists.updateOne(
        {"user_id": userID,  "lists.$.list_id": listID }, 
        {
        $addToSet: { "lists.$.practiced_words": { $each: wordIDs}}, 
        $set: { 
            "lists.$.last_practiced": last_practiced,
            $inc: {"lists.$.wordCount": numberOfNewWords}
            }
        }
    )

    return lists
}

let userID = "609b974f6bd8dc6019d2f304"
let listData = {
    list_id: "609d22188ea8aebac46f9dc3",
    last_practiced: "03-04-2021 13:25:10",
    word_ids: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"],
}

word.updatePersonalWordLists(userID, listData).then(res => console.log(res))
```

**My scheme**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const personalWordListsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user_id: {
    type: String
  },
  lists: Array
});

module.exports = personalWordListsSchema
```

I hope someone can help me to figure this out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try leaving out the `$` in the filter portion, like `"lists.list_id": listID`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked! Can you explain why it's like that? Shouldn't be "lists.list_id" undefined?

Comment: The MongoDB query language lets you directly refer to a key in an object in an array using that notation.  The `$` operator is used in the update to indicate the array object that satisfied the filter, so the `$` has no special meaning in the query part.

Comment: Alright, got it! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @joe's comment I was able to make it work.

I removed the `$` from the filter portion and used the ´´´$inc´´´ outside of the ´´´$set´´´ portion.

- Word IDs are pushed only if they are unique.
- Date of last practice can be updated.
- Word count increments too.

```
    const list = await personalWordLists.updateOne(
        {"user_id": userID,  "lists.list_id": listID }, 
        {
        $addToSet: { "lists.$.practiced_words": { $each: wordIDs}}, 
        $set: { 
            "lists.$.last_practiced": last_practiced
            },
        $inc: {"lists.$.wordCount": numberOfNewWords}
        }
    )

    return list
```